# Check if user signed in from html

Tags: html, asp.net, ajax, authentication

Is there a proper way to check from html file if user is signed in to her ASP.NET account beside making an ajax call to server ?

Answer (score 0):

either make a call to the server or have the server put a hidden input in the HTML to indicate so.

like

```
<input id="is-user-logged-in" type="hidden" value="true"/>
```

Edit:
Both the response you got from server and the value you read from hidden input should be used only for UI stuffs. Any operation that requires login HAS to be checked again by the server on request.

I.E. you may enable the change password button if your client side detection shows the user has logged in. But the actual change password call would need to validate again to make sure.

Comment: @Shai Keep in mind even a user familiar with the most extreme basics of HTML could manipulate this value if they wanted to. It shouldn't be relied on by the server side.

Comment: @mason The value should be used to alter some UI or enable some buttons only. The login check for all those actions will be checked by the server again so I see no issue with that.

Comment: I can see you know that, but it seems like you're trying to speak for Shai, who may not know that.